# Can't produce and consume events to and from Kafka in same spring boot application

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

1. Running Kafka on my local machine `localhost:9092`
2. Created a topic `ProductOrders` with `Replica 1` and `Partition 3`
3. Created a `spring-boot 2.4.3`, `spring-kafka 2.6.6` and `spring-cloud-stream 3.1.1` application with a POJO OrderEvent, OrderEventPublisher, and OrderEventConsumer
4. Want to publish `OrderEvent` on the topic `ProductOrders` and consume `OrderEvent` from the topic `OrderEvent`
5. Running the application, I can't see OrderEvent(s) being published or consumed through the application.  Also verified, even the `kafka-console-consumer` can't see the events.

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud.stream:
    bindings:
      orderCreated-out-0:
        destination: ProductOrders
      processOrder-in-0:
        destination: ProductOrders
    kafka.streams.broker:
      configuration:
        commit.interval.ms: 1000
        default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
        default.value.serde: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
        spring.json.trusted.packages: '*'
        spring.json.value.default.type: com.poc.kafka.orderanalytics.events.OrderEvent
      brokers: localhost:9092
      serdeError: logAndContinue

  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
```

`OrderEventPublisher.java`

```
public class OrderEventPublisher {
    @Bean
    public Supplier<OrderEvent> orderCreated() {
        log.info("Configuring Order Data");
        Map<String, String[]> orders = new HashMap<>();
        orders.put("home_appliances", new String[] {"Toaster","Grill","Veg Cutter"});
        orders.put("gardening", new String[] {"Coco Pit","Vermi Compost","Petunia Seeds"});
        orders.put("toys", new String[] {"Dump Truck","Fighter Jet","Fire Truck"});
        orders.put("books", new String[] {"Let Us C","Effective Java","Apache Kafka, complete guide"});
        orders.put("cloths", new String[] {"T Shirt","Short","Vests"});
        return () -> {
            log.info("Creating order");
            String category = (String) orders.keySet().toArray()[new Random().nextInt(orders.size())];
            String name = orders.get(category)[new Random().nextInt(orders.get(category).length)];
            OrderEvent orderEvent = new OrderEvent();
            orderEvent.setCategory(category);
            orderEvent.setName(name);
            orderEvent.setQuantity(1);
            return orderEvent;
        };
    }
}
```

`OrderEventConsumer.java`

```
public class OrderEventConsumer {
    @Bean
    public Consumer<OrderEvent> processOrder() {
        log.info("Consuming the order");
        return orderEvent -> {
          log.info("Order Consumed with category: {}, name: {}, qty: {}",orderEvent.getCategory(), orderEvent.getName(), orderEvent.getQuantity());
        };
    }
}
```

**If I break producer and consumer into two different spring boot applications, all work as expected.  What could be the issue that it doesn't work when both producer and consumer exists in a single spring boot application?**

Comment: This should work perfectly fine. I can't see any issues in your configuration. Perhaps you can post/push a slimmed down version of your project - just a bare minimum to reproduce the issue so we can take a look? Also, any stack trace or things in the log that you may have missed?

Comment: In addition to what Oleg suggested in the above comment, you also don't need any configuration for `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams..` as I don't see the use for Kafka Streams in your application.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg for the response.   I pushed minimal application at:
[link](https://github.com/ajoshi83/orderanalytics/tree/master)

Comment: @sobychacko thanks.  I will remove the streams config but I have a plan to use Kafka steams later once the application behaves as expected.

Comment: Hi, Try to share a minimally reproducible example, and then we can triage further.

Comment: @sobychacko, thanks.  I pushed my minimally reproducible code at Github.  The link :   

[link](https://github.com/ajoshi83/orderanalytics/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delay in response. There was an issue with the application's configuration. Since you have two different functions in the application, you need to tell the framework which functions need to be activated. After adding the following configuration, I was able to run the application and then produce/consume the data.

```
spring.cloud.function.definition: orderCreated;processOrder
```